# Can I duplicate a GA4 property?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a website, let's call it "X" and I tagged it using Google Tag Manager and I track it using Google Analytics 4.  I duplicated the website (let's call it "Y") and I need to tag it again with GTM and track it with GA4.  Do I have to tag and track everything again from scratch or can I duplicate GA4's property and GTM's container and make changes to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new Property to configure in GA4 and retrieve the measurement id. For the GTM you can export the container and import it into a new one after which only change the measurement id with the new one.

Comment: I understood the GTM part. What do you mean by "retrieve the measurement ID"? I understand that I need to create a new property in GA4 and use it's ID to link GTM. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I mean it.